# Why does Google Analytics report higher "organic search" on days with lots of Reddit referrals?

Tags: seo, search

The following data comes from Google Analytics. Site is new. The site gets a traffic spike when published on Reddit, along with the traffic increase comes the "organic search" increase. Then when the traffic goes down after a few day s(which is expected because the traffic comes from Reddit), the "organic search" numbers also goes down.

I don't understand why organic search would also have peaks during the few days that matches the days with traffic from Reddit. Should they be unrelated?

(Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/85tjsm/webassembly_cant_access_the_dom_what/)

From Google Analytics:

```
day | total visits | from organic searches 
----|--------------|---------------------- 
20  | 1153         | 476
21  | 740          | 236
22  | 80           | 32
```

Comment: Is your site webassembly.org? Then i wonder, how you even get to know about reddit traffic - reddit is https, your site is http, with this moving vector users should lose referrer.

Comment: The site is https://webassemblycode.com.

Comment: **https**, forgot to mention

Answer (score 1):

On the basis that Google ranks sites based on their relevance to the user for a particular search topic, and one of the key ways that they do this is by assessing backlinks from popular sites, I would expect that whenever your page link is published on Reddit you will naturally see a positive corresponding movement in your organic search positioning, especially as it is a new site.

After all, that is a key point of having quality backlinks to your site.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that there are no obscure issues, I would highly recommend adding UTM tracking to all links you post. This was you can tell Google Analytics exactly where the traffic has come from.

Just remember to turn on UTM tracking in your GA Property Settings > Advanced Settings

Also, a great UTM builder can be found here https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/